# C linked list: Placing number infront of the list and making all numbers shift

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying get the method `shiftInsert` to work. I want to insert a number into the list and make the last number disappear. If this is the list `p   1  -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`, after `shiftInsert(8)` the list needs to look like this `p  8 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`. As you can see the last number needs to disappear. How do I implement this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct elem {
    int value;
    struct elem *next;
};

typedef struct elem Node;

Node *root;

Node * addElem(Node *p, int value) {
    p->next = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p = p->next;
    p->value = value;
    p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

void shiftInsert(Node *n, int v) {
    int tmp;

    while (n != NULL) {
        Node * new_node;
        new_node = malloc(sizeof (new_node));
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void printList() {
    Node *p = root;

    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%2d -> ", p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }

    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Node *p;
    int i = 0;

    root = p = malloc(sizeof (Node));
    p->value = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        p = addElem(p, i);
    }

    printList();
    shiftInsert(root, 88);
    printList();
    shiftInsert(root->next->next->next, 33);
    printList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So your question is ... *how do I implement this*? You're gonna have to be a little more specific.

Comment: You want to insert only into the first position?

Comment: Why not just update the `next` pointer in the next-to-last node to point to `NULL`, make the last node the new head, update its value and update the `next` pointer to point to the old head.

Comment: The way you ask the question suggests that you want a function that takes only a value as input and inserts that value at the head of the list, removing the last node. But your code suggests that you want to be able to insert the node anywhere in the list. You should be more specific in your question.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Yes i want to insert into the beginning of the list, and make the last number go away

Comment: @Teuntje Check my answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your example, you want to insert into the first position and remove the last one. So basically you want to create a new root then find the last but one element and set its `next` to `NULL`.

So first the delete function:

```
void deleteLast()
{
    int i, before_last = 0;
    Node *temp;

    /* Find last element to remove it*/
    temp = root;

    for(i = 0; temp->next != NULL; i++) { // "i" will be the index of the last element
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    before_last = i - 1; // the one before "i" will be the new last element
    temp = root;

    for(i = 0; i < before_last; i++) { // find the one before last and set its "next" NULL
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    free(temp->next);
    temp->next = NULL;
}
```

New root, create an element which will be the new root. Set its `next` to root, then make the new element as the root.

```
void shiftInsertRoot(int v) {

    if (root != NULL) {
        Node * new_root;
        /* Create new root */
        new_root = malloc(sizeof (new_root));
        new_root->next = root; // save previous root
        new_root->value = v;   // set new value
        root = new_root;       // update root pointer

        deleteLast();
    }
}
```

---

According to your main, you want to insert after a certain element, you have to find it first. Then create a new element and set its `next` to the `next` of the original element, so you won't lose the rest of the list. Finally set the `next` of the original element to the new element.

```
void shiftInsertAnywhere(Node *position, int v) {
    int i;
    Node *temp;

    temp = root;

    for(i = 0; temp->value != position->value; i++) {

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp != NULL) {
        Node * new_root;
        /* Create new root */
        new_root = malloc(sizeof (new_root));
        new_root->next = temp->next; // save the rest of the list
        new_root->value = v;         // set new value
        position->next = new_root;   // insert the new element after "position" element

        deleteLast();
    }
}
```

This will insert after the `position`.

Example:

```
printList();
shiftInsertRoot(88);
printList();
shiftInsertRoot(33);
printList();
shiftInsertAnywhere(root->next->next, 99);
printList();
shiftInsertAnywhere(root, 17171);
printList();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Because you insert the new node after the node `position` given to your `shiftInsertAnywhere()` function, this function can' t insert a new node into the head position of a list.

Comment: @DavidBowling There is a separate function for that purpose: `void shiftInsertRoot(int v)`. I mentioned that `shiftInsertAnywhere()` will insert after `position`.

Comment: My point was that you have three functions where one, or maybe two if you really want to keep the `deleteLast()` function, would do.

Comment: @DavidBowling Two functions with two different purposes. Shared part in a third function, which function can be even useful anywhere later on.  I think it is easier to read the code this way, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to allocate new space to insert nodes without growing the list. Here is a function that inserts a node at the head of the list, and drops the last node:

```
Node * shiftInsert(Node *n, int v) {
    Node *tail = n;

    if (n == NULL){
        return n;
    } else if (n->next == NULL) {
        n->value = v;
        return n;
    }
    while (tail->next->next != NULL)
        tail = tail->next;
    tail->next->value = v;
    tail->next->next = n;
    n = tail->next;
    tail->next = NULL;

    return n;
}
```

Notice that this version of `shiftInsert()` returns a pointer to the head of the list.

Here is a second function that allows you to insert a node anywhere in the list, and drops the last node:

```
Node * shiftInsertAny(Node *root, Node *n, int v) {
    Node *tail = n;
    Node *insert = root;

    if (root == NULL){
        return root;

    } else if (root->next == NULL) {
        root->value = v;
        return root;

    }
    while (n != root && insert->next != n)
        insert = insert->next;
    if (insert->next->next == NULL) {
        insert->next->value = v;
        return root;
    }
    while (tail->next->next != NULL)
        tail = tail->next;
    tail->next->value = v;
    tail->next->next = n;
    if (insert == root)
        root = tail->next;
    else
        insert->next = tail->next;
    tail->next = NULL;

    return root;
}
```

This function also returns a pointer to the head of the list, and takes both a pointer to the head of the list, and a pointer to the insertion point as arguments. The new node is inserted in front of the node indicated by the pointer `n`.

If you call these functions like this in your code:

```
printList();
root = shiftInsert(root, 88);
printList();
root = shiftInsertAny(root, root->next->next->next, 33);
printList();
```

this is the output:

```
1 ->  2 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 ->  9 -> 10 -> NULL
88 ->  1 ->  2 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 ->  9 -> NULL
88 ->  1 ->  2 -> 33 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 -> NULL
```

I updated the above code snippet for the `shiftInsertAny()` function. I had made a change to allow it to insert a node at the head of the list, but I forgot to edit the code snippet earlier. With this function you can insert into the first node or the last node. For example, with a 5-element list, you can do:

```
printList();
root = shiftInsertAny(root, root, 88);
printList();
root = shiftInsertAny(root, root->next->next->next->next, 33);
printList();
```

which has output:

```
1 ->  2 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 -> NULL
88 ->  1 ->  2 ->  3 ->  4 -> NULL
88 ->  1 ->  2 ->  3 -> 33 -> NULL
```